# How to cancel out denominator without expanding the numerator

Tags: algebra

I am trying to do algebra the way we do by hand.  For example,

```
test1=(x - b^2 + 3/(x-a)) + ((x+b)^2/((x-a)*(x+a))+z+(x+x)^3/(x-a))
test2=(x-a)*(x+a)
test3=test2*test1
```

output is:

```
 (x-a)*(x+a)*(x - b^2 + 3/(x-a)) + ((x+b)^2/((x-a)*(x+a))+z+(x+x)^3/(x-a))
```

but it should be:

```
 (x*(x-a)*(x+a) - b^2*(x-a)*(x+a) + 3*(x+a)) + ((x+b)^2)+z*(x-a)*(x+a)+(x+x)^3*(x+a))
```

I have tried Distribute, Factor, Cancel, Simplify but all of them expand everything and do not remove the denominator.  It also removes the powers in terms.
How to tell mathematica to eliminate denominator and without expanding numerators?

Comment: Maybe `Apart[test3]` or `Simplify@Apart[test3]` ?

Comment: Depending on how general you want it to be, there are many ways: `test2 # & /@ test1`, `Block[{test2}, Distribute[test2*test1]]`, `Distribute[factor*test1] /. factor -> test2`, `Module[{p}, Distribute[test3 /. #] /. Reverse@# &[test2 -> p]]`.

Comment: I have tried all of your codes for a simple function and it works.  But for my complicated one it does not.   I found a suspect but I am not sure why.  I used the Denominator[function1]  where the function is in the matrix form.  I was able to get denominator.   Then I created another function2 to do determinant of function1.  It calculated the determinant which is function3 (my goal) .  However when I do Denominator[function3] it returns 1.   There is no denominator which is wrong.  I do not know why it does not see denominator.  I guess I am doing something wrong to declare a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute) is that the sums in `test2` are getting distributed as well as the sum in `test3`. You could achieve what you want if the sums in `test2` were inactive, so the following use of [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate)/[`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive) can be used to solve your problem:

```
Activate @ Distribute[Inactivate[Evaluate@test2, Plus] test1]
```

> 3 (a + x) + 8 x^3 (a + x) - b^2 (-a + x) (a + x) + 
>    x (-a + x) (a + x) + (b + x)^2 + (-a + x) (a + x) z

**Update**

The OP is using M9, and [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive) was introduced in M10. There is no need to use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive) for this problem, the key is to change the head [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus) to something else before using [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute). So, in M9 the following should work:

```
Distribute[ReplaceAll[test2, Plus->plus] test1] /. plus->Plus
```

> 3 (a + x) + 8 x^3 (a + x) - b^2 (-a + x) (a + x) + 
>    x (-a + x) (a + x) + (b + x)^2 + (-a + x) (a + x) z

Comment: @Woll, it does not work (Math v9)

Comment: @Woll, okay it works now.  Thank you for help.

Comment: @Woll, I marked as solved because you solved my example problem.   For my actual much longer and complex problem it does not work but I expected it anyway.  I can proceed manually anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I solved the problem by simplifying(Factor, Distribute etc)  matrix instead using its determinant result to simplify.  Looks like determinant result was too complicated for mathematica to deal with.